# Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-requests, discord.py

I'm trying to grab multiple *keys?* from a dictionary using a discordpy command but they have the same name. Here is the code of my command suppose to grab the key values:

```
@bot.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    url = "https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get"
    req = requests.get(url)
    data = req.json()
    store = data["items"]["item"]["names"]
    await ctx.send(store)
```

But I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I used the exact same method for a different dictionary and it worked but the *key?* names were all different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is a dictionary, but `data['items']` is a list, so you can't do `data['items']['item']`.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/store/get")
>>> data = r.json()
>>> type(data['items'])
<class 'list'>
```

It's a list of dictionaries, so this works:

```
>>> for item in data['items']:
...   print(item['item']['name'])
...
Cat's Claws
Batglider
Catwoman Comic Book Outfit
Whipcrack
Extraterrestrial
Caped Crusader
Commando
Bat Signal
Zorgoton
Team Space
Full tilt
```